# Finding the highest and lowest rates of increase at specific x value across several time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to attempt to determine the difference between the highest and lowest rates of increase across a series of dataframes at a specified x value. As shown below, the dataframes have basic x and y columns, with emissions values in the x column, and precipitation values in the y column. Among the dataframes, the idea would be to determine the highest and lowest rates of precipitation increase at "approximately" 1 Terratons of emissions (TtC) relative to the first value of each time series. For example, I want to figure out which dataframe has the highest increase at 1 TtC, and which dataframe has the lowest increase at 1 TtC. at However, I am not sure if there is a way to quickly achieve this? Here are the dataframes that I created, followed by an example of how each dataframe is structured:

#Dataframe objects created:

```
CanESMRCP8.5PL<-data.frame(get3.teratons, pland20) 
IPSLLRRCP8.5PL<-data.frame(get6.teratons, pland21)
IPSLMRRCP8.5PL<-data.frame(get9.teratons, pland22)
IPSLLRBRCP8.5PL<-data.frame(get12.teratons, pland23)
MIROCRCP8.5PL<-data.frame(get15.teratons, pland24)
HadGEMRCP8.5PL<-data.frame(get18.teratons, pland25)
MPILRRCP8.5PL<-data.frame(get21.teratons, pland26)
GFDLGRCP8.5PL<-data.frame(get27.teratons, pland27)
GFDLMRCP8.5PL<-data.frame(get30.teratons, pland28)
```

#Example of what each of these look like:

```
>CanESMRCP8.5PL

    get3.teratons   pland20
X1      0.4542249 13.252426
X2      0.4626662  3.766658
X3      0.4715780  2.220986
X4      0.4809204  8.495072
X5      0.4901427 10.206458
X6      0.4993126 10.942797
X7      0.5088599  6.592956
X8      0.5187588  2.435796
X9      0.5286758  2.275836
X10     0.5389284  5.051706
X11     0.5496212  8.313389
X12     0.5600628  9.007722
X13     0.5708608 11.905644
X14     0.5819234  6.126022
X15     0.5926283  9.883264
X16     0.6042306  7.699696
X17     0.6159752  5.614193
X18     0.6274483  6.681527
X19     0.6394011 10.112812
X20     0.6519496  8.721810
X21     0.6646344 10.315931
X22     0.6773436 11.372490
X23     0.6903203  8.662169
X24     0.7036479 10.106109
X25     0.7180955 10.990867
X26     0.7322746 13.491778
X27     0.7459771 17.256650
X28     0.7604589 12.040960
X29     0.7753096 10.638796
X30     0.7898374  7.889500
X31     0.8047258 11.757174
X32     0.8204160 15.060151
X33     0.8359387  9.822078
X34     0.8510721 11.388695
X35     0.8661237 10.271567
X36     0.8815913 13.224285
X37     0.8984146 15.584782
X38     0.9154501  9.320024
X39     0.9324529  9.187128
X40     0.9497379 12.919805
X41     0.9672824 15.190318
X42     0.9854439 12.098606
X43     1.0041460 16.758629
X44     1.0241779 17.435182
X45     1.0451656 15.323428
X46     1.0663605 18.292109
X47     1.0868977 12.625429
X48     1.1079376 17.318583
X49     1.1295719 14.056624
X50     1.1516720 18.239445
X51     1.1736696 16.312087
X52     1.1963065 18.683315
X53     1.2195753 20.364835
X54     1.2425277 14.337167
X55     1.2653873 16.072449
X56     1.2888002 14.870248
X57     1.3126799 18.431717
X58     1.3362459 19.873449
X59     1.3593610 17.278361
X60     1.3833589 18.532887
X61     1.4083234 16.178170
X62     1.4328881 17.689810
X63     1.4572568 21.395131
X64     1.4821021 20.154886
X65     1.5072721 15.655971
X66     1.5325393 21.692028
X67     1.5581797 23.258303
X68     1.5842384 23.802459
X69     1.6108635 15.824673
X70     1.6365393 19.016228
X71     1.6618322 20.957593
X72     1.6876948 19.105363
X73     1.7134712 19.759288
X74     1.7392598 27.315595
X75     1.7652725 24.882263
X76     1.7913807 25.813408
X77     1.8173818 23.658997
X78     1.8434211 24.223432
X79     1.8695911 23.560818
X80     1.8960611 28.057708
X81     1.9228969 26.996265
X82     1.9493552 26.659719
X83     1.9759324 22.723687
X84     2.0026666 30.977267
X85     2.0290137 29.384326
X86     2.0549359 24.840383
X87     2.0811679 26.952620
X88     2.1081763 29.894790
X89     2.1349227 25.224040
X90     2.1613017 27.722623

>IPSLLRRCP8.5PL

    get6.teratons   pland21
X1      0.5300411  8.128827
X2      0.5401701  6.683660
X3      0.5503503 12.344974
X4      0.5607762 11.322411
X5      0.5714146 14.250646
X6      0.5825357 10.013592
X7      0.5937966  9.437394
X8      0.6051673  8.138396
X9      0.6168960  9.767765
X10     0.6290367  8.166579
X11     0.6413864 12.307348
X12     0.6539184 12.623931
X13     0.6667360 11.182448
X14     0.6800060 12.585040
X15     0.6935350 13.408614
X16     0.7071757  9.352335
X17     0.7211951 12.743725
X18     0.7356089 11.625612
X19     0.7502665 10.240418
X20     0.7650959 12.394282
X21     0.7800845 16.963066
X22     0.7953119 16.380090
X23     0.8107459 10.510501
X24     0.8260236 12.645911
X25     0.8414439 14.134851
X26     0.8572960 18.924963
X27     0.8732313 17.849050
X28     0.8892344 10.941533
X29     0.9057380 12.034925
X30     0.9223530 15.897904
X31     0.9391578 19.707692
X32     0.9563358 16.690375
X33     0.9738711 18.098571
X34     0.9916517 16.588447
X35     1.0096934 16.125172
X36     1.0279473 19.108647
X37     1.0463864 16.972994
X38     1.0653421 22.869403
X39     1.0842487 21.228874
X40     1.1035309 25.509754
X41     1.1230403 15.579367
X42     1.1426743 21.259726
X43     1.1626806 26.061262
X44     1.1833831 21.918530
X45     1.2045888 22.369094
X46     1.2262981 21.480456
X47     1.2481395 20.503543
X48     1.2703019 27.717028
X49     1.2929382 26.295449
X50     1.3157745 28.271455
X51     1.3390449 31.595651
X52     1.3626052 26.188018
X53     1.3863833 26.326999
X54     1.4102701 26.902272
X55     1.4343871 25.308764
X56     1.4584666 23.789699
X57     1.4831504 26.916504
X58     1.5080384 32.921638
X59     1.5331210 29.753267
X60     1.5582794 29.567720
X61     1.5832585 31.454097
X62     1.6085002 26.602191
X63     1.6339502 35.873728
X64     1.6594560 34.222654
X65     1.6851070 36.290959
X66     1.7109757 31.623912
X67     1.7368503 31.965520
X68     1.7626750 41.490310
X69     1.7883216 35.645934
X70     1.8141292 35.639422
X71     1.8405670 37.085608
X72     1.8672313 44.812777
X73     1.8939987 40.044602
X74     1.9208222 37.834526
X75     1.9478806 44.497335
X76     1.9750195 39.839740
X77     2.0024118 38.300529
X78     2.0302205 52.116649
X79     2.0581589 59.189047
X80     2.0861536 51.559857
X81     2.1141780 43.305779
X82     2.1421791 47.950074
X83     2.1703249 46.252149
X84     2.1985953 47.536605
X85     2.2266540 49.422466
X86     2.2547762 44.577399
X87     2.2827062 49.720523
X88     2.3102098 47.138244
X89     2.3379090 51.882832
X90     2.3656370 51.413472
```

Etc...

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,